# Compute the rolling minimum in data.table with adative window

Tags: r, data.table

I want to compute a rolling minimum for each group over an adaptive rolling window. I've currently done this using `frollapply` but I get `NA` until there are enough rows for the window size.

I need the window to be adaptive so that if the window is say 3, then on rows 1 and 2 the window will also be 1 and 2 and then 3 for the remaining rows.

```
d = structure(list(x = c(10, 4, 8, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10),
                   grp = c(rep("a", 6), rep("b", 3))),
              row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

window <- 4
d[, n := {x = 1:.N; y = .N; z = fifelse(x > window, window, x)}, by = .(grp)]

d[, x1 := frollmean(x, n, adaptive=TRUE), by = .(grp)]
d[, x2 := frollapply(x, n, FUN = min), by = .(grp)]
d[, x3 := frollapply(x, n = 4, FUN = min), by = .(grp)]
```

In the example above the window size is `4`, `n` is a the adaptive window. The mean in `x1` is using the window and I need the same thing but for the minimum. When I tried using this in `x2` and it just returns the same value in `x`.
If I use `n=4` in the frollapply then I get `NA` until there are enough rows to satisfy the window length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something quick with `fcoalesce()`:

```
d[, xx := fcoalesce(frollapply(x, n = window, FUN = min), cummin(x)), by = grp]
# or 
d[, xx := fcoalesce(frollapply(x, n = window:1L, FUN = min)), by = grp]


    x grp xx
1: 10   a 10
2:  4   a  4
3:  8   a  4
4:  1   a  1
5:  2   a  1
6:  3   a  1
7:  8   b  8
8:  9   b  8
9: 10   b  8
```